# Android Studio: Change String array value from POST API method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, okhttp

I'm working for an Android app project which is used to call POST API service to get the return value and output to a `listview` in an activity. I'm using `okhttpclient` in this project. Previously, I hard-coded the `titles[]` value which is `"111","222","333"...`. I want to change the `titles` value when I get return value from POST API method. The result `titles` get from POST method is `{KL City Tour, Sunway Lagoon, Klang Bak Kut Teh, ...}`

How can it be done? Here is my code:

```js
package com.example.nextplt.vendorapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class ProductListingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String ac_token = "";

    public String[] titles ={
            "111",
            "222",
            "333",
            "444",
            "555",
            "666",
            "777",
            "888",
            "999",
            "000",
    };

    String[] prices ={
            "RM100",
            "RM200",
            "RM200",
            "RM20",
            "RM100",
            "RM200",
            "RM200",
            "RM20",
            "RM200",
            "RM20"
    };

    // Array of booleans to store toggle button status
    public boolean[] status = {
            true,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false,
            false
    };

    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.drawable.vendor_icon,
            R.drawable.rightarrow,
            R.drawable.rightarrow,
            R.drawable.rightarrow,
            R.drawable.vendor_icon,
            R.drawable.rightarrow,
            R.drawable.rightarrow,
            R.drawable.rightarrow,
            R.drawable.vendor_icon,
            R.drawable.rightarrow,
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_listing);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String access_token = intent.getStringExtra("access_token");
        Toast.makeText(ProductListingActivity.this,access_token,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ac_token = access_token;

        runThread();
        createListView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id){
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProductListingActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("access_token",ac_token);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void createListView(){

        ListView lvProductListing = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.plListView);

        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lv, View item, int position, long id) {

                ListView lView = (ListView) lv;

                SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) lView.getAdapter();

                HashMap<String,Object> hm = (HashMap) adapter.getItem(position);

                /** The clicked Item in the ListView */
                RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) item;

                /** Getting the toggle button corresponding to the clicked item */
                Switch tgl = (Switch) rLayout.getChildAt(3);

                String strStatus = "";
                if(tgl.isChecked()){
                    tgl.setChecked(false);
                    strStatus = "Off";
                    status[position]=false;
                }else{
                    tgl.setChecked(true);
                    strStatus = "On";
                    status[position]=true;
                }
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), (String) hm.get("txt") + " : " + strStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        lvProductListing.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

        // Each row in the list stores country name and its status
        List<HashMap<String,Object>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            hm.put("txt", titles[i]);
            hm.put("price",prices[i]);
            hm.put("image",imageId[i]);
            hm.put("stat",status[i]);
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = {"txt","price","image","stat" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.PLtitle, R.id.PLprice, R.id.list_image, R.id.PLtoggle};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_productlisting, from, to);

        lvProductListing.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void getVendorList() throws IOException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2/departsoon-api-mobile/public/api/vendor/get-vendor-list?" +
                "type=0&page=1&access_token=" + ac_token;
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        String result = response.body().string();
        System.out.println("First" +result);

        try {
            JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(result);
            System.out.println("Second" + Jobject);
            JSONObject jo_data = Jobject.getJSONObject("vendorList");
            System.out.println("Third" +jo_data);
            JSONArray ja_data = jo_data.getJSONArray("data");
            System.out.println("Four" +ja_data);
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                JSONObject jObj = ja_data.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println(jObj.getString("over_title"));
                titles[i]=jObj.getString("over_title");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            response.body().close();
        }
    }

    public void runThread () {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    getVendorList();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: application]

Here is sample response from API:

```js
{
  "vendorList": {
    "total": 26,
    "per_page": 10,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 3,
    "next_page_url": "http://localhost/departsoon-api-mobile/public/api/vendor/get-vendor-list?page=2",
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 10,
    "data": [
      {
        "type": 2,
        "over_title": "KL City Tour",
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2016-01-02 00:33:46",
        "updated_at": null,
        "rating": 0,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "pac_amount": 60,
        "status": 1,
        "photo_name": "bukit-bintang-1",
        "photo_ext": "jpg",
        "total_guest": null,
        "total_revenue": null,
        "total_booking": 0
      },
      {
        "type": 4,
        "over_title": "Sunway Lagoon Theme Park",
        "id": 2,
        "created_at": "2016-01-02 00:50:01",
        "updated_at": "2016-01-06 12:30:25",
        "rating": 0,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "pac_amount": 24,
        "status": 1,
        "photo_name": "vuvuzela_big",
        "photo_ext": "jpg",
        "total_guest": "16",
        "total_revenue": 380,
        "total_booking": 5
      },
      {
        "type": 1,
        "over_title": "Klang Bak Kut Teh Food Tour",
        "id": 3,
        "created_at": "2016-01-04 14:21:11",
        "updated_at": "2016-01-25 00:32:02",
        "rating": 0,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "pac_amount": 12,
        "status": 1,
        "photo_name": "img_0703",
        "photo_ext": "jpg",
        "total_guest": "4",
        "total_revenue": 80,
        "total_booking": 2
      },
      {
        "type": 3,
        "over_title": "JB Setia Tropika Eco B&B",
        "id": 4,
        "created_at": "2016-01-04 15:07:13",
        "updated_at": null,
        "rating": 0,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "pac_amount": 60,
        "status": 1,
        "photo_name": "01877171e16be21302ef9332e37e8bbc09eec2f915",
        "photo_ext": "jpg",
        "total_guest": null,
        "total_revenue": null,
        "total_booking": 0
      },
      {
        "type": 5,
        "over_title": "Car Rental in KL",
        "id": 5,
        "created_at": "2016-01-04 15:24:45",
        "updated_at": null,
        "rating": 0,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "pac_amount": 60,
        "status": 1,
        "photo_name": "toyota-vellfire-2013-7",
        "photo_ext": "jpg",
        "total_guest": null,
        "total_revenue": null,
        "total_booking": 0
      },
      {
        "type": 6,
        "over_title": "KL to Singapore",
        "id": 6,
        "created_at": "2016-01-04 16:27:31",
        "updated_at": "2016-01-23 18:46:18",
        "rating": 0,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "pac_amount": 120,
        "status": 1,
        "photo_name": "037780-luggage",
        "photo_ext": "jpg",
        "total_guest": "3",
        "total_revenue": 300,
        "total_booking": 2
      },
      {
        "type": 7,
        "over_title": "KLIA/KLIA2 <> Klang Valley",
        "id": 7,
        "created_at": "2016-01-04 16:35:25",
        "updated_at": "2016-01-23 18:42:31",
        "rating": 0,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "pac_amount": 24,
        "status": 0,
        "photo_name": "KLIA",
        "photo_ext": "jpg",
        "total_guest": "1",
        "total_revenue": 50,
        "total_booking": 1
      },
      {
        "type": 7,
        "over_title": "Test airport transfer",
        "id": 8,
        "created_at": "2016-01-04 23:39:19",
        "updated_at": null,
        "rating": 0,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "pac_amount": 12,
        "status": 0,
        "photo_name": null,
        "photo_ext": null,
        "total_guest": null,
        "total_revenue": null,
        "total_booking": 0
      },
      {
        "type": 1,
        "over_title": "test",
        "id": 9,
        "created_at": "2016-01-15 00:35:12",
        "updated_at": null,
        "rating": 0,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "pac_amount": 24,
        "status": 0,
        "photo_name": null,
        "photo_ext": null,
        "total_guest": null,
        "total_revenue": null,
        "total_booking": 0
      },
      {
        "type": 5,
        "over_title": "driver asd dds sda",
        "id": 10,
        "created_at": "2016-01-15 16:09:02",
        "updated_at": null,
        "rating": 0,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "pac_amount": 11,
        "status": 0,
        "photo_name": "terrorist-alert",
        "photo_ext": "jpg",
        "total_guest": null,
        "total_revenue": null,
        "total_booking": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  "upcoming": [],
  "departed": [
    {
      "departed": 1,
      "id": 7,
      "departed_guest": "1",
      "departed_revenue": 50
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you share the sample response with full data for one request?

Comment: i added the response below the image. Hope you can help me, thx